# jquery page load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get page load to work, but instead of making js for each button I want it to go through the `ul` and get the value from each `li`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#nav").children().each($(this).on("click", function() {
    $("#main").load("/pages/" + $(this).data("page") + ".php");
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li data-page="home" id="a">Home</li>
    <li data-page="page-2" id="b">Page 2</li>
    <li data-page="page-3" id="c">Page 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The error I'm getting is this

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.call is not a function
at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at k.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (page-load.js:17)
at e (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at t (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com) -> [Iterating over jQuery and non-jQuery Objects](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/)

Comment: List items can't have a value attribute. A data attribute would probably make more sense

Comment: @j08691 They can, but only in an `<ol>` and it would have to be a number, [4.4.7 The `li` element -> Content attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/grouping-content.html#the-li-element): _"If the element is a child of an `ol` element: `value` - Ordinal value of the list item"_

Comment: @j08691 i just changed it to use the data attribute and changed the js a little but it still dont work and tbh its the js i need more help with then the html

Comment: You have to pass a function to `.each()` and not a jQuery object/collection

Comment: @Andreas, `each(...)` has multiple signatures. 1) `$.each(array, function(index, element){})` 2) `$('selector').each(function(index){}). In the case of the OP yes, `.each(...)` would be #2. Just a note, #1's `element` and #2 uses `this` are going to be the DOM element, not a jQuery element

Comment: @Itanex There's a difference between `$.each(...)` and `$(selector).each()`. And OP is clearly not using `$.each()` hence it should be a function. And even when it would have been '$.each()` then the second parameter had to be a function and not `undefined`

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for repeating what I just said. 1) there is a difference multiple signatures. 2) the OP uses the selector rooted signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#nav").children().each($(this).on("click", function () {` is wrong - I can see what you were intending, but

a) ".each" expects a callback function as input, not a jQuery collection (hence the error message), and

b) it's not necessary to use a loop for this anyway.

The whole line could be simplified to `$("#nav li").click( function () {` . jQuery will ensure that each of the list items gets a separate click handler attached to it.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#nav li").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data("page"));
    $("#main").load("/pages/" + $(this).data("page") + ".php");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li data-page="home" id="a">Home</li>
    <li data-page="page-2" id="b">Page 2</li>
    <li data-page="page-3" id="c">Page 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Update the `nav` link to only select LI that contain the `data-page` attribute (`#nav li[data-page]`) to prevent LI getting click event handling when it is not present and causing additional errors. You will get page requests to `/pages/.php` which will return 404s.

Comment: thanks alot i should probaly have mentioned that i knownext to nothing about js/jquery (because of bad teachers back in the days) and are just really starting to learn to use it now

Comment: @Itanex sure you could but there's no indication that there would ever _not_ be a page specified - it's a menu of links, why would there not be a page attribute provided? What would be the purpose of the menu item in that situation? I'd expect it to be considered a bug in the HTML if a page attribute was missing. And attribute selectors are more expensive, so we should avoid them unless it's 100% necessary.

Comment: @ADyson, correct we don't know, we also don't know either way or what the intent was of the original author beyond what we see in the OP. It will help the OP to know that if the Menu contains other LI with no attribute, such as a Title entry, as is common in the bootstrap nav demos, that additional errors will occur when allowing a greedy selector operates. As for the speed issues of attribute selectors, since this selector runs once, it has `nil` of an impact, which can be reduced to 0 using a deferred pattern `$('#nav').on('click', '[data-page]', function(){...});`

Comment: @Itanex but again...**why** would the menu contain an entry with no page? What use would that be? And how are demos relevant? They never represent reality. I really think you're splitting hairs here

Comment: @ADyson For a real example check out this site's side bar navigation. Where it says `home`, `public`, etc. `nav>ol[class]>li>a|li>ol[class]`. Explore a few CSS frameworks for similar template/demos. Your solution creates multiple bindings, total of O(n) where n is the number of `LI`s, also lending itself to n memory resident bindings. Using the deferred process creates O(1) where the binding is 1 event handler on the `#nav` and the handler filtering the `[data-page]`. This also prevents issues where `LI`s don't have a `[data-page]` due to being not present or spelled wrong.

Comment: @Itanex you're speculating about a structure the OP doesn't have.